# Do changes to elasticsearch mapping apply to already indexed documents?

Tags: elasticsearch

If I change the mapping so certain properties have new/different boost values, does that work even if the documents have already been indexed? Or do the boost values get applied when the document is indexed?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot change field level boost factors after indexing data. It's not even possible for new data to be indexed once the same fields have been indexed already for previous data.

The only way to change the boost factor is to reindex your data. The pattern to do this without changing the code of your application is to use aliases. An alias points to a specific index. In case you want to change the index, you create a new index, then reindex data from the old index to the new index and finally you change the alias to point to the new index. Reindexing data is either supported by the elasticsearch library or can be achieved with a scan/scroll.

1. First version of mapping

   Index: items_v1

   Alias: items -> items_v1
2. Change necessary, sencond version of the index with new field level boost values :

   Create new index: items_v2

   Reindex data:     items_v1 => items_v2

   Change alias:     items -> items_v2

This might be useful in other situations where you want to change your mapping.

Field level boosts are, however, not recommended. The better approach is to use boosting at query time.

Alias commands are:

**Adding an alias**

```
POST /_aliases
{
    "actions": [
            { "add": {
            "alias": "tems",
            "index": "items_v1"
        }}
    ]
}
```

**Removing an alias**

```
POST /_aliases
{
    "actions": [
            { "remove": {
            "alias": "tems",
            "index": "items_v1"
        }}
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

They do not.

Index time boosting is generally not recommended. Instead, you should do your boosting when you search.

Comment: Can you point to documentation on this? The reason I'm not doing search-time boosting is because I'm using a simple query-style search.

Comment: Never mind, looks like this is fairly straightforward! http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#_multi_field_2